# React does not recognize the computedMatch prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to use global header but I have a problem. I want to use it like this:

```
const Main = () => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={FrontLogin} />
      <Route path="/register" component={FrontRegister} />
    </Switch>
    <Switch>
      <div id="test">
        <Header />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={FrontHome} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/:username" component={FrontProfile} />
        <Redirect to="/home" />
      </div>
    </Switch>
  </>
);
```

**index.js**

```
render() {
  return (
    <Provider {...Store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route component={Main} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

According to some sources, it is said that such a usage is not correct and when I use it like this I get an error like this: **React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element.** So how can I solve this problem and how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reorganize your code a little, moving the div and header outside the Switch

```
const Main = () => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={FrontLogin} />
      <Route path="/register" component={FrontRegister} />
      <Route>
        <div id="test">
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={FrontHome} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/:username" component={FrontProfile} />
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </>
);
```

`Switch` is used only to render routes exclusively, no need to put other kinds of components there

**UPDATE**

Since you don't want to show the content of the second `Switch`, you can nest the routes in the default route of the first `Switch`, so when it doesn't match the login or register it goes to the other routes

Comment: it is working not exactly. <Header /> is not supposed to work on login and registration routes.

Comment: @32quick23 I updated my answer, let me know if that works